# Hadoop: Output file has double output

Tags: python, hadoop, cluster-computing, reduce, mapper

I am running a Hadoop program and have the following as my input file, *input.txt*:

```
1
2
```

*mapper.py*:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line,
print "Test"
```

*reducer.py*:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line,
```

When I run it without Hadoop:
**$ cat ./input.txt | ./mapper.py | ./reducer.py**, the output is as expected:

```
1
2
Test
```

However, running it through Hadoop via the streaming API (as described [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/#run-the-mapreduce-job)), the latter part of the output seems somewhat "doubled":

```
1
2
Test    
Test
```

Aditionally, when I run the program through Hadoop, it seems like it has a 1/4 chance of failing due to this:

> Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1.

I've looked at this for some time and can't figure out what I'm not getting.  If anyone could help with these issues, I would greatly appreciate it!  Thanks.

edit: When *input.txt* is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The output is:

```
1   
10  
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   
7   
8   
9   
Test    
Test
```

Comment: I tried it and I am getting the same output even with hadoop streaming!

Comment: @Amar Very weird.  It definitely doubles it for me.

Comment: Can you post the output Hadoop shows on the screen after you submit your job using the command you indicated (`bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar \ -file /hadoop/mapper.py -mapper mapper.py -file /hadoop/reducer.py -reducer reducer.py -input /hadoop/input.txt -output /hadoop/output`)?

Comment: @cabad  This is stated in the post -- the output is `1,2,Test,Test` with the commas representing line breaks.

Comment: I understand this. I mean the rest of the output; this provides information about how Hadoop is running your code.

Comment: @cabad I'm sorry -- I'm not quite sure what you mean, as that is the entire output.   I have tried the same code with the input being the numbers 1-10, each on a new line, and will update this in the post.

Comment: @cabad If there is a specific input file you'd like me to test, please let me know.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, I guess my terminology was confusing. I don't mean the output in "output.txt". I mean the output on the screen (i.e., on `stdout`).

Comment: @cabad Oh, gotcha.  Other than the map and reduce percentages and a tracking URL, there is no information provided.

Comment: @cabad I'm wondering if it might be related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188263/hadoop-and-python-disable-sorting

Comment: Sigh... I am not sure if you really wan't help or not. "Other than the map and reduce percentages and a tracking URL, there is no information provided." Are you sure? Don't you have a line that says "Total input paths to process : x"?

Comment: @cabad Yes, sorry.  I assumed this was reflecting what's written in the command-line entry.  It says `Total input paths to process : 1`

Comment: Ok, then I have no idea why you get that output. I can only think of three alternatives: (1) your input.txt file in HDFS has a "Test" string in the last line, (2) you are mistakenly using your mapper as reducer, or (3) you have, by mistake, added a print "Test" statement at the end of your reducer.

Comment: @cabad Thanks for trying, it's certainly weird.  I have double-checked that none of those 3 possibilities are occurring.

Answer (score 0):

It gives the same output. I guess you are specifying the location of reducer to mapper.py only.
Make sure you are providing correct path to reducer.py

Comment: I have tried this and unfortunately run into the same issue.  This is the console command: `bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar \ -file /hadoop/mapper.py -mapper mapper.py -file /hadoop/reducer.py -reducer reducer.py -input /hadoop/input.txt -output /hadoop/output`

Comment: Any ideas?  No idea why this is happening :(